# Does Java support anonymous functions in a similar way to scala?

Tags: java, scala, lambda, anonymous-function

I am working on the Scala function below that explores the use of anonymous functions. Is there a way this could be recreated in Java? I have attached the Scala code as well as the Java code I have attempted.

```
def filter (lst:List[Int], fn:(Int)=>Boolean):List[Int] = 
{
var res:List[Int] = Nil
lst.foreach ((x:Int)=>if (fn(x)) res = x::res)
return res.reverse
}

val list = List.range(0, 10)
println(filter(list, x => x % 2 == 0))
```

Above is in Scala.
I have attempted to recreate this in Java but get an error

```
public static void filter(List<Integer> lst, Function <Integer,Boolean> func) {
    List<Integer> res;
    for (if (func.apply(lst)):
         ) {

    }

}
```

Overall the code line I'm having difficulty recreating is this line:
lst.foreach ((x:Int)=>if (fn(x)) res = x::res)
from the scala code

Edit: I have attempted in Java again but I get an error Cannot invoke "java.util.List.stream()" because "res" is null

```
  Function <Integer,Boolean> fn =  x -> x % 2 == 0;
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10);
    
    System.out.println (filter(list,fn));

}
public static int filter(List<Integer> lst, Function <Integer,Boolean> func) {
    List<Integer> res = null;
    res.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Java has lambdas ... from Java 8 onwards.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class TestFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<Integer, Boolean> fn = x -> x % 2 == 0;

        List<Integer> res = filter(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), fn);
        System.out.println(res);
    }


    public static List<Integer> filter(List<Integer> list, Function<Integer, Boolean> func) {
        return list
                .stream() // convert into stream
                .filter(func::apply) // apply the filter
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()) //reverse the order
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // convert into List
    }
}
```

Comment: I think reversal is not needed. In scala `x::res` creates the resulting list in reverse order, so there an undoing reverse was needed.  Also `sorted` then needed `naturalOrder` first. Not important, but `Predicate<Integer>`/``test` is a bit more concise as `Function<Integer, Boolean>`/`apply`.